# Cómo puedo con JavaScript, mediante expresiones regulares, separar con el método split por varios separadores

Tags: javascript, split

Necesito mediante el método split separar el texto por dos separadores. Sin usar expresiones regulares solo permite un separador.

Los separadores tienen que ser el "." y la "?".

```
let texto = "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam perferendis repellendus ipsam optio, odit ipsa reiciendis quod omnis eaque nostrum, quisquam quibusdam fugiat eligendi odio ducimus aspernatur praesentium? Ipsa, accusantium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi porro neque dolorem fuga iste? Necessitatibus delectus maiores, perferendis quo numquam exercitationem mollitia! Dolores maxime omnis possimus dolorem."

let exRegular = texto.split()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes hacerlo con expresiones regulares.

```
let exRegular = texto.split(/\.|\?/);
```

usar \ para que no actue como parte de la expresión regular. y mas como un String